# Pandas Splitting a Row into Multiple Rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an input row in a table/dataframe like this :

```
        0                                     1                2
```

1. Period Description Start Date End Date 8/1/2015 7/31/2016 8/1/2016 7/31/2017
   3
   8/1/2017 7/31/2018

Output required:

```
       0           1        2         3
 1. Start Date 8/1/2015  8/1/2016  8/1/2017  

 2. End Date   7/31/2016 7/31/2017 7/31/2018
```

Is this possible? I'm not sure how to proceed with this, splitting the row in two rows.. "Period Description" text is not required in the column.
where 0, 1 ,2 & 3 column headers..

0th column header has: Period Description Start Date End Date,
1st Column header has :8/1/2015 7/31/2016,
2nd column header has : 8/1/2016 7/31/2017

and so on...

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the original dataset in a tabular format?

Comment: Based on the input you can try, ```finds = re.findall("\d+/\d+/\d+", input_); finds[::2]; finds[1::2]```

Comment: @Sushanth yes, i'm able to use this one perfectly.. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple split and join approach would work just fine.

```
>>> a='Period Description Start Date End Date 8/1/2015 7/31/2016 8/1/2016 7/31/2017 8/1/2017 7/31/2018'
>>> a.split()
['Period', 'Description', 'Start', 'Date', 'End', 'Date', '8/1/2015', '7/31/2016', '8/1/2016', '7/31/2017', '8/1/2017', '7/31/2018']
>>> b = a.split()[2:]
>>> b
['Start', 'Date', 'End', 'Date', '8/1/2015', '7/31/2016', '8/1/2016', '7/31/2017', '8/1/2017', '7/31/2018']
>>> c = [' '.join(b[:2]),*b[4:-3]]
>>> c
['Start Date', '8/1/2015', '7/31/2016', '8/1/2016']
>>> d = [' '.join(b[2:4]),*b[-3:]]
>>> d
['End Date', '7/31/2017', '8/1/2017', '7/31/2018']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([c,d])
>>> df
           0          1          2          3
0  Start Date   8/1/2015  7/31/2016   8/1/2016
1    End Date  7/31/2017   8/1/2017  7/31/2018
```